ssh on KDE keeps showing a GUI asking for a password
Since upgrading to Kubuntu 24.04, I am prompted by a GUI requesting a password the first time I ssh to a new server (and subsequently later after a timeout, it seems).
I have tried disabling kdewallet and also uninstalling ksshaskpass, and unsetting  SSH_ASKPASS in the environment. It feels like some sort of keyring but I don't know what.
My keys exist in the ssh-agent (verified with ssh-add -l).
For some servers, the required password is my login password rather than the actual key password. It's possible that I messed something up during the upgrade when prompted to provide a password, but I don't recall exactly.
ssh -vv shows
debug1: Will attempt key: <keyname> RSA SHA256:<shasum> explicit agent
debug1: Offering public key: <keyname> RSA SHA256:<shasum> explicit agent
debug1: Server accepts key: <keyname> RSA SHA256:<shasum> explicit agent



I discovered that my $SSH_AUTH_SOCK was referencing gpg-agent, not ssh-agent.
For want of a better solution, in my .config/autostart-scripts/ssh-add.sh script, I additionally added:
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket
unset SSH_ASKPASS
unset SSH_ASKPASS_PREFER

The additional unset SSH_ASKPASS commands were required to make a QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread error go away.
